# What is a "balad"?

Tags: meaning

What is a balad as use in this [blog](http://blog.withings.com/en/2013/07/22/activity-tracking-why-is-it-important-to-measure-elevation/) entry?

> You get an interesting feedback when you consult the elevation data on
>   your Pulse. After a balad or a race you can instantly see how many
>   feet/meters you’ve moved vertically. You can even try to guess it with
>   your friends!

Comment: Looks lie a typo to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.engadget.com/2013/08/16/withings-pulse-review/) Withings is a French company.

`Balad` or `Balade` is the French word for walk or stroll.

This site has this [definition](http://www.lingo2word.com/lingodetail.php?WrdID=272888):  `go (walk) is used in French`